# Pegar o valor do ComboBox automaticamente com Jquery via POST

Tags: javascript, jquery

Não sei se fui claro no título, mas quem é da antiga deve lembrar que o Dreamweaver tinha uma função de Jump que era muito usada em combobox. Como eu faria essa opção com Jquery dentro do seguinte raciocínio:

```
<label for="filtro">Registros:</label>
<select name="Filtrar" id="filtro" class="form-control">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

Ao selecionar a quantidade do registro desejado, eu pegasse como post diretamente e jogasse dentro desse método automaticamente:

```
        $filtro = $_POST["Filtrar"];
   echo $metodos->listarUsuarios($filtro);
```

**Método listarUsuarios()**

```
 public function listarUsuarios($filtro)
    {
       $limite = ($filtro == '')?'10':$filtro;
       $sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM tabela LIMIT ".$limite.";");
      .....
    }
```

Isso é possível com Jquery? Pode ser com JavaScript também.

Comment: Putz. Tem razão LeAndrade. Eu havia esquecido completamente desse post! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O script jQuery que retorna o valor de uma opção de um elemento `select` quando se escolhe uma delas é o seguinte:

```js
$('#filtro').on('change', function(){
  let quantidade = $(this).val();
  console.log(quantidade);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="filtro">Registros:</label>
<select name="Filtrar" id="filtro" class="form-control">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

> **Nota**: O script pode ser criado com Vanilla JS

Comment: Obrigado Maujor